pytonconnect | Aiogram | Python how to send transaction in different coin
I am using pytonconnect, specifically tonkeeper wallet, I need to send money in the TON network, but with a different currency (e.g. web3) how can I do this?
async def send_transaction(call: CallbackQuery,db:MDB,lang):
    connector = get_connector(call.from_user.id)
    connected = await connector.restore_connection()
    if not connected:
        await con_wallet_alert(call,lang)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await disconnect_wallet(call=call,db=db,lang=lang)
        return

    user=await db.users.find_one({"_id":call.from_user.id})
    sub_pay=user['sub_pay']
    word=symbol_to_word(sub_pay)
    price = user.get('price',1)
    transaction = {
        'valid_until': int(time.time() + 3600),
        'messages': [
            get_comment_message(
                destination_address=os.getenv("TONKEEPER_WALLET",""),
                amount=int(int(price) * 10 ** 9),
                comment=comment(lang,sub_pay)
            )
        ]
    }
    await approve_trans(call,lang)
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(connector.send_qtransaction(
            transaction=transaction
        ), 300)
        await db.users.find_one_and_update({'_id': call.from_user.id},{'$set':{'sub_type': sub_pay}})
        await order_success(message=call.message,sub=sub_pay,lang=lang)

Where can I specify which currency to use?
Maybe I need to use an address, or need to add something? I can't find any documentation on this.

You need to replace (or change) get_comment_message like this:
from pytoniq_core import begin_cell
from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode

def get_jetton_transfer_message(jetton_wallet_address: str, recipient_address: str, transfer_fee: int, jettons_amount: int, response_address: str = None) -> dict:
    data = {
        'address': jetton_wallet_address,
        'amount': str(transfer_fee),
        'payload': urlsafe_b64encode(
        begin_cell()
        .store_uint(0xf8a7ea5, 32)  # op code for jetton transfer message
        .store_uint(0, 64)  # query_id
        .store_coins(jettons_amount)
        .store_address(recipient_address)  # destination address
        .store_address(response_address or recipient_address)  # address send excess to
        .store_uint(0, 1)  # custom payload
        .store_coins(1)  # forward amount
        .store_uint(0, 1)  # forward payload
        .end_cell()  # end cell
        .to_boc()  # convert it to boc
        )
        .decode()  # encode it to urlsafe base64
    }

    return data

and transaction body should be as in the example:
transaction = {
    'valid_until': int(time.time() + 3600),
    'messages': [
        get_jetton_transfer_message(
        jetton_wallet_address='EQCXsVvdxTVmSIvYv4tTQoQ-0Yq9mERGTKfbsIhedbN5vTVV',
        recipient_address='0:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        transfer_fee=int(0.07 * 10**9),
        jettons_amount=int(0.01 * 10**9),  # replace 9 for jetton decimal. For example for jUSDT it should be (amount * 10**6)
        response_address=wallet_address
        ),
    ]
}

Full documentation: https://docs.ton.org/develop/dapps/ton-connect/message-builders

When I try to pay a transaction to a wallet, I get an unknown error in TonKeeper itself, but in the bot itself it thinks it has successfully paid.
https://tonviewer.com/transaction/18e2a27e947f41e16f78e47c2de43d4e487f517316d2b05e5cdd260ebe352ab7

TonConnect  cannot verify the success of the transaction, it just reports that the user has sent the transaction. To check the status of a transaction, you can use, for example, tonapi.io
